# @twilio/flex-webchat-ui how to integrate in my react redux project

Tags: reactjs, redux, twilio-flex

How to integrate `@twilio/flex-webchat-ui` in my react+redux project

I created a Twilio Flex account, but I don't know how to integrate the webchat in my project. I've read Twilio Flex documentation, but it didn't help. Can anyone help me, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to integrate Twilio Webchat is by using a CDN version. In order to do so:

1. Add this code snippet to your HTML page

```html
<script src="https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/flex-webchat/releases/2.1.2/twilio-flex-webchat.min.js">
  const appConfig = {
    accountSid:"AC...",
    flexFlowSid:"FO..."
  };
  Twilio.FlexWebChat.renderWebChat(appConfig);
</script>
```

2. Replace `AC...` and `FO...` in the snippet above by your Flex credentials

You can read more about alternative installation paths here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/installing-and-using-flex-webchat